# Foswiki SolrPlugin cannot add a topic

Tags: solr, vagrant, vagrant-plugin, foswiki

I use [this](https://github.com/LCIre/FoswikiVagrantNginx) guide to install Foswiki from master github repository using Nginx as Webserver.

```
cd /<foswiki-dir>/tools
./solrindex topic=Main.WebHome
```

No topic is created and these errors appears

> Not a HASH reference at
>   /var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki/Engine/CLI.pm line 113. Undefined
>   subroutine &Foswiki::encode_utf8 called at
>   /var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki/Response.pm line 431. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki.pm
>   line 646. Compilation failed in require at ./solrindex line 30. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at ./solrindex line 30. Can't call method
>   "finalize" on an undefined value at
>   /var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki/Engine/Legacy.pm line 72. END
>   failed--call queue aborted at ./solrindex line 30.

Can you help me please?

Comment: cd /<foswiki directory>/tools
and then i use unix command
./solrindex topic=Main.WebHome

Comment: apt-get update ,
apt-get install libany-moose-perl ,
apt-get install libxml-easy-perl , 
apt-get install libfile-mmagic-perl, 
I have already install this libraries

Answer (score 0):

The posted error message refers to

```
Not a HASH reference at
/var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki/Engine/CLI.pm line 113.
```

That part of the code varies considerably between versions. In 2.1.2 it is

> ```
> 113     my %uploads;
> ```

And in 2.0.3 it is

> ```
> 113 sub finalizeHeaders { }
> ```

Neither makes sense of the message. **So can you tell me what Foswiki version you are running**?

The message:

> Undefined subroutine &Foswiki::encode_utf8 called at
>   /var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki/Response.pm line 431.

seems to suggest something wrong in the environment. Foswiki::encode_utf8 is defined in Foswiki.pm. Either you have an old version, or the code does not find Foswiki.pm. Strange, since it did find Foswiki.pm but did not compile, according to:

> compilation aborted at /var/www/fw-prod/core/lib/Foswiki.pm line 646

Anyway, for debugging in and Apache/Foswiki configuration I use (from my makefile):

```
 FOSWIKI_HOME=/home/bram/devfoswiki/core  
 FOSWIKI_LIBS=${FOSWIKI_HOME}/lib:${FOSWIKI_HOME}/lib/CPAN/lib

 export FOSWIKI_HOME=${FOSWIKI_HOME}; export FOSWIKI_LIBS=${FOSWIKI_LIBS}
```

before executing the command line. Maybe that will help.

In your response, can you please refer to the versions of software you are using? It helps understanding the error messages.